# Appending to an array access by a key in Redux Reducer

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to add to my state within a reducer. I need to access a key, and then add to an array within that key. This is what my state currently looks like:

```
{teamMembers: {
    PersonId1: [{ object1 }, {object2 }]
    PersonId2: [{ object3 }, { object4 }]
    PersonId3: [{ object5 }, { object6 }]
}}
```

I need to access a `PersonId`, based on what the action inputs, and then append an item from the action to the array. Ideally it would also create a new key and array if the key `PersonId` didn't already exist.

Comment: have you tried `teamMembers[id] = [...teamMembers[id], ...newArray]` ?

Comment: Because it is in a return I can't do `teamMembers[id]` - accessing a key like `object[key]` gives a syntax error

Comment: Use an auxiliary function where you pass as arguments the state and the action, returning the state manipulated as you wish.

Comment: @sam 1. You can. 2. You don't have to do it inside a `return`. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48776888/3148807) for code examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your reducer, just do a little data manipulation. Remember to only manipulate a copy of your state and not your actual state.

```
const action = {
  payload: {
    personId: 'PersonId4',
    item: {}
  }
}

const state = {
    PersonId1: [{ object1 }, {object2 }]
    PersonId2: [{ object3 }, { object4 }]
    PersonId3: [{ object5 }, { object6 }]
}
const {personId, item} = action.payload
let newState = {...state}
if (personId in newState) {
  newState[personId].push(item)
} else {
  newState[personId] = [item]
}
return newState
```

Comment: Didn't even occur to me to do things outside the return. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally check for the existence of the key and then add it to an already existing array or create a new one.

Something like this:

```
const newItems = state[id] ? [...state[id], ...items] : items;
//...
return {
  ...state,
  [id]: newItems
}
```

Note that i'm using the object spread syntax which [is a proposal (in stage 3](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread)) and you need the babel plugin [`babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/) to support it (or [babel stage 3 preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-3/)).

Running example:

```js
const initialState = {
  teamMembers: {
    PersonId1: [{
      name: 'object1'
    }, {
      name: 'object2'
    }],
    PersonId2: [{
      name: 'object3'
    }, {
      name: 'object4'
    }],
    PersonId3: [{
      name: 'object5'
    }, {
      name: 'object6'
    }]
  }
};

const actionOne = {
  type: 'ADD',
  payload: {
    id: 'PersonId2',
    items: [{
      name: 'object444'
    }]
  }
}

const actionTwo = {
  type: 'ADD',
  payload: {
    id: 'PersonId777',
    items: [{
      name: 'object777'
    }]
  }
}

const reducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD':
      {
        const {
          id,
          items
        } = action.payload;
        const newItems = state[id] ? [...state[id], ...items] : items;
        return {
          ...state,
          [id]: newItems
        }
      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const reducerResultOne = reducer(initialState.teamMembers, actionOne);
console.log('reducerResultOne', reducerResultOne);
const reducerResultTwo = reducer(initialState.teamMembers, actionTwo);
console.log('reducerResultTwo', reducerResultTwo);
```